# How to write tests for Rails 5 controller that uses a session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I’m following the book Agile web development with Rails 5.1 and I got stuck integrating my test cases with an exercise proposed in the “Play time” section. We are building a online store that has a `cart`  the cart has_many `line_items`, so far so good, one of the exercises was prevent someone from accessing any cart but the one on their session, easy enough (I thought) and created the following validation:

```
def show
    invalid_cart if @cart.id != session[:cart_id]
end
private
    def invalid_cart
      logger.error "Attempt ot access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to store_index_url, notice: 'Invalid cart'
    end
```

Well that works on the browser but that broke my tests for example, I had:

```
setup do
    @cart = carts(:one)
  end
...
  test "should show cart" do
    get cart_url @cart
    assert_response :success
  end
```

It fails because it is not a response 200 it a response 300 for the redirect I did when the session[:cart_id] was not the same (inside the invalid_cart method), I tried something like:

```
  test "should show cart" do
    get cart_url @cart, params: { session: { cart_id: @cart.id } }
    assert_response :success
  end
```

but this seems to be frown upon (’https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23386#issuecomment-178013357').

So I’m a little bit lost here. how should the verification for a valid cart be normally implemented? and still have meaningful tests.

thanks your for time

Comment: Look up `request.session`, then set that in your test. And congrats on learning testing!

Comment: Thanks @Phlip! request.session helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap: set `request.session[:cart_id]` in the assembly phase of your test case.

Comment: Do you have a solution for a test that extends `ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase`? I'm getting a NameError in my Selenium-driven system test case when accessing `session`.

Comment: gotta write a new top-level question (after asking ChatGPT). I no longer work in Rails (ad I disapprove of DHH's recent architectural decisions)